# Creating templates dynamically from JSON in AngularJS

Tags: json, angularjs

I am parsing or reading a JSON file in my AngularApp. I want to create one template for each object inside the JSON file, and then load it with "previous" and "next" in my app.

So i have a JSON file, for example:

```
{
  "name": "test", 
  "objects":[
    {"one": "text here", "id" : "1" }, 
    {"two": "and text there", "id" : "2" }
  ]
}
```

So i want to create a template called "template1" and "template2".

I am starting with Angular, so i don't need a whole workaround, just where do i have to dig deeper?

1. I created a controller for my app
2. I've then created a jsonService which injectes the controller
3. Now i have the JSON data

But what then? Do i have to create Directives? And how to load them into my main-page? With data-ng-view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Nikos for this possibility. I found a much simpler soultion:

I hard coded a `ng-switch on="option"` and then a `ng-switch-when="optionN"` in each div, so i can dynamically adjust one template to fit all options.

Answer (score 1):

See this example which will give you an example of how you can iterate over json and render to html:

https://github.com/eu81273/angular.treeview/blob/master/angular.treeview.js